# Coloring line segments using plot() in Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

If I create a plot and use `segments` to color segments in a line it will reuse the plot created before that with `plot()`

```r
plot(data[18000:(18000+2000)], type='l')
segments(stOdds, data[stOdds], stEvens, data[stEvens], col="blue", lwd=2)
```

However, it does not work calling `plot()` twice:

```r
plot(data[18000:(18000+2000)], type='l')
plot(data[18000:(18000+200)], type='l', col='blue')
```

How can I color segments of lines in a plot?

Comment: Have you tried with `lines` ? Like `lines(data[18000:(18000+200)], type='l', col='blue')` after your `plot(data[18000:(18000+2000)], type='l')`

Comment: @PierreChevallier Interesting. This works. Maybe it is because I am used to Python's `matplotlib` but I expected some kind of handle to a plot such that I can modify further things like axis labels etc.

Comment: If your new line has different range than the first one, try plotting the area without displaying data first `plot(data, type="n")` and then add the respective lines onto the plot area.